# ¿Como hacer una consulta de Cloud Firestone con un limit desde y hasta?

Tags: android, firebase

Buenas comunidad, estoy haciendo una Query en Firebase Firestone en android y me he encontrado que no puedo hacer una consulta con un limit desde y hasta, lo que es SQL sería limit 0,5 por ejemplo, mirando la documentación realmente no encuento que den solución a este problema, por lo que vengo aquí para ver si teneís alguna idea de como lo puedo hacer, la idea es que vaya de 5 en 5. Aquí os dejo el código, cada vez que el usuario pulsa a un boton, un contador se incrementa y es donde hace el limit. Un saludo y gracias:

```
 db.collection("incidencias").whereEqualTo("activa",true).orderBy("t_stamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(vez+5).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot> documentos= (ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>) task.getResult().getDocuments();

                    for(int i=0; i<documentos.size(); i++){
                        DocumentSnapshot datos=documentos.get(i);
                        IncidenciaItem incidenciaItem=new IncidenciaItem(datos.getString("titulo"),
                                datos.getDate("t_stamp"),datos.getString("usuario"),datos.getString("descripcion"),
                                datos.getString("img1"),datos.getString("img2"),datos.getString("img3"),
                                datos.getString("direccion"),datos.getGeoPoint("coordenadas"),String.valueOf(datos.getId()),
                                datos.getBoolean("activa"));

                        adaptador.anadirElementos(incidenciaItem);

                    }

                    adaptador.notificarCambio();
                    cargaLista(true);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Quizá lo que estás necesitando es paginar los resultados, [la documentación oficial explica en qué consiste y cómo hacerlo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors?hl=es-419). Creo que esto podría resolver tu problema de una forma satisfactoria.

Comment: Eso es, mucha gracias compañero @A.Cedano